# How to write condition with regular expression?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, regular-expression

I'm aware of the following comparison:

```
if @% == "/tmp/crontab.zi5NeVPGRc"
  set nobackup
  set nowritebackup
  set noundofile
  set noswapfile
endif
```

But how can I use regular expression? For example if the filename contains "crontab", then do this and that?

Comment: As asked, and based on the fact that you've chosen [toro2k's answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2741/64), this question is actually not related to filenames at all; it could be repurposed as a general question about matching regular expressions in VimScript. On the other hand, it feels like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and [Carpetsmoker's answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2742/64) does a great job of addressing what I believe you were actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: @tommcdo I've re-edited the question for more general purpose as suggested and toro2k answer say exactly how to write regular expression condition (as per main question). The other answer deals only with specific case and focus on autocmd and filename, but it doesn't answer the main question (how to write simple regular expression condition), that's why I've chosen toro2k answer (which is more appropriate in this case).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just have to use one of [the regular expression match operators](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-%3D%7E). For example, using `=~#` to perform a case sensitive match:

```
if @% =~# 'crontab'
  # the file name contains 'crontab', 
  # do this and that
endif
```

Answer (score 8):

Use an autocmd. Your vimrc file is executed *only* the first time Vim starts.

In fact, `filetype.vim` should already do this:

```
" Crontab
au BufNewFile,BufRead crontab,crontab.*,*/etc/cron.d/*      call s:StarSetf('crontab')
```

So you can use:

```
au FileType crontab setlocal backupcopy=yes
```

Setting `nobackup` is not required.

Note I'm also using `setlocal`, to prevent leaking this setting to other buffers, consider when you use `crontab -e` and then `:tabe /other_file`. Your `:set` commands will then 'leak' to this new buffer.

If you don't want to rely on the filetype for some reason:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead crontab,crontab.*,*/etc/cron.d/* setlocal backupcopy=yes
```

Comment: While @toro2k answered OP's question directly, this answer solves the problem more appropriately. It's kind of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).